# Speech assistant - raspberry pi

Tags: python

I have created this code but I don't know why the microphone is not working in raspberry but it's working in computer. Whatever I say, the program doesn't output anything I said.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import pyaudio

r = sr.Recognizer()                                                                         #starting the speech_recognition recognizer
r.pause_threshold = 0.7                                                                     #it works with 1.2 as well
r.energy_threshold = 400

os.system("espeak 'Welcome with Teacher Assitant Bot, Feel free to ask me anything you want to ask'")
print("Welcome with Teacher Assitant Bot, Feel free to ask me anything you want to ask")

while True:                                                                                 #The main loop

    with sr.Microphone(device_index = 7, sample_rate = 44100, chunk_size = 512) as source:

        try:

            audio = r.listen(source, timeout = None)                                        #instantiating the Microphone, (timeout = None) can be an option
            message = str(r.recognize_google(audio))
            print('You said: ' + message)

            if google in message:                                                           #what happens when google keyword is recognized

                words = message.split()
                del words[0:2]
                st = ' '.join(words)
                print('Google Results for: '+str(st))
                url='http://google.com/search?q='+st
                webbrowser.open(url)
                v.speak('Google Results for: '+str(st))

            elif hello in message:
            os.system("espeak 'Hello'")
            print("hello")          

            elif acad in message:                                                           #what happens when acad keyword is recognized

                words = message.split()
                del words[0:2]
                st = ' '.join(words)
                print('Academic Results for: '+str(st))
                url='https://scholar.google.ro/scholar?q='+st
                webbrowser.open(url)
                os.system("espeak 'Academic Results for: '+str(st)")

            elif wkp in message:                                                            #what happens when wkp keyword is recognized

                try:

                    words = message.split()
                    del words[0:3]
                    st = ' '.join(words)
                    wkpres = wikipedia.summary(st, sentences=2)

                    try:

                        print('\n' + str(wkpres) + '\n')
                        os.system("espeak 'wkpres'")

                    except UnicodeEncodeError:
                        os.system("espeak 'wkpres'")

                except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
                    print (e.options)
                    v.speak("Too many results for this keyword. Please be more specific and try again")
                    continue

                except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError as e:
                    print('The page does not exist')
                    v.speak('The page does not exist')
                    continue

            elif sc in message:                                                             #what happens when sc keyword is recognized

                try:
                    words = message.split()
                    del words[0:1]
                    st = ' '.join(words)
                    scq = cl.query(st)
                    sca = next(scq.results).text
                    print('The answer is: '+str(sca))
                    #url='http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i='+st
                    #webbrowser.open(url)
                    v.speak('The answer is: '+str(sca))

                except StopIteration:
                    print('Your question is ambiguous. Please try again!')
                    v.speak('Your question is ambiguous. Please try again!')

                else:
                    print('No query provided')

            elif paint in message:                                                          #what happens when paint keyword is recognized
                os.system('mspaint')

            elif rdds in message:                                                           #what happens when rdds keyword is recognized
                print("Reading your text")
                v.speak(pyperclip.paste())

            elif sav in message:                                                            #what happens when sav keyword is recognized
                with open('path to your text file', 'a') as f:
                    f.write(pyperclip.paste())
                print("Saving your text to file")
                v.speak("Saving your text to file")

            elif bkmk in message:                                                           #what happens when bkmk keyword is recognized
                shell.SendKeys("^d")
                v.speak("Page bookmarked")

            elif keywd in message:                                                          #what happens when keywd keyword is recognized

                print('')
                print('Say ' + google + ' to return a Google search')
                print('Say ' + acad + ' to return a Google Scholar search')
                print('Say ' + sc + ' to return a Wolfram Alpha query')
                print('Say ' + wkp + ' to return a Wikipedia page')
                print('Say ' + book + ' to return an Amazon book search')
                print('Say ' + rdds + ' to read the text you have highlighted and Ctrl+C (copied to clipboard)')
                print('Say ' + sav + ' to save the text you have highlighted and Ctrl+C-ed (copied to clipboard) to a file')
                print('Say ' + bkmk + ' to bookmark the page your are currently reading in your browser')
                print('Say ' + vid + ' to return video results for your query')
                print('For more general questions, ask them naturally and I will do my best to find a good answer')
                print('Say ' + stoplst + ' to shut down')
                print('')

            elif vid in message:                                                            #what happens when vid keyword is recognized

                words = message.split()
                del words[0:2]
                st = ' '.join(words)
                print('Video Results for: '+str(st))
                url='https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='+st
                webbrowser.open(url)
                v.speak('Video Results for: '+str(st))

            elif wtis in message:                                                           #what happens when wtis keyword is recognized

                try:

                    scq = cl.query(message)
                    sca = next(scq.results).text
                    print('The answer is: '+str(sca))
                    #url='http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i='+st
                    #webbrowser.open(url)
                    v.speak('The answer is: '+str(sca))

                except UnicodeEncodeError:

                    v.speak('The answer is: '+str(sca))

                except StopIteration:

                    words = message.split()
                    del words[0:2]
                    st = ' '.join(words)
                    print('Google Results for: '+str(st))
                    url='http://google.com/search?q='+st
                    webbrowser.open(url)
                    v.speak('Google Results for: '+str(st))

            elif wtar in message:                                                           #what happens when wtar keyword is recognized

                try:

                    scq = cl.query(message)
                    sca = next(scq.results).text
                    print('The answer is: '+str(sca))
                    #url='http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i='+st
                    #webbrowser.open(url)
                    v.speak('The answer is: '+str(sca))

                except UnicodeEncodeError:

                    v.speak('The answer is: '+str(sca))

                except StopIteration:

                    words = message.split()
                    del words[0:2]
                    st = ' '.join(words)
                    print('Google Results for: '+str(st))
                    url='http://google.com/search?q='+st
                    webbrowser.open(url)
                    v.speak('Google Results for: '+str(st))

            elif whis in message:                                                           #what happens when whis keyword is recognized

                try:

                    scq = cl.query(message)
                    sca = next(scq.results).text
                    print('\nThe answer is: '+str(sca)+'\n')
                    v.speak('The answer is: '+str(sca))

                except StopIteration:

                    try:

                        words = message.split()
                        del words[0:2]
                        st = ' '.join(words)
                        wkpres = wikipedia.summary(st, sentences=2)
                        print('\n' + str(wkpres) + '\n')
                        v.speak(wkpres)

                    except UnicodeEncodeError:

                        v.speak(wkpres)

                    except:

                        words = message.split()
                        del words[0:2]
                        st = ' '.join(words)
                        print('Google Results (last exception) for: '+str(st))
                        url='http://google.com/search?q='+st
                        webbrowser.open(url)
                        v.speak('Google Results for: '+str(st))

            elif whws in message:                                                           #what happens when whws keyword is recognized

                try:

                    scq = cl.query(message)
                    sca = next(scq.results).text
                    print('\nThe answer is: '+str(sca)+'\n')
                    v.speak('The answer is: '+str(sca))

                except StopIteration:

                    try:

                        words = message.split()
                        del words[0:2]
                        st = ' '.join(words)
                        wkpres = wikipedia.summary(st, sentences=2)
                        print('\n' + str(wkpres) + '\n')
                        v.speak(wkpres)

                    except UnicodeEncodeError:

                        v.speak(wkpres)

                    except:

                        words = message.split()
                        del words[0:2]
                        st = ' '.join(words)
                        print('Google Results for: '+str(st))
                        url='http://google.com/search?q='+st
                        webbrowser.open(url)
                        v.speak('Google Results for: '+str(st))

            elif when in message:                                                         #what happens when 'when' keyword is recognized

                try:

                    scq = cl.query(message)
                    sca = next(scq.results).text
                    print('\nThe answer is: '+str(sca)+'\n')
                    v.speak('The answer is: '+str(sca))

                except UnicodeEncodeError:

                    v.speak('The answer is: '+str(sca))

                except:

                    print('Google Results for: '+str(message))
                    url='http://google.com/search?q='+str(message)
                    webbrowser.open(url)
                    v.speak('Google Results for: '+str(message))

            elif where in message:                                                        #what happens when 'where' keyword is recognized

                try:

                    scq = cl.query(message)
                    sca = next(scq.results).text
                    print('\nThe answer is: '+str(sca)+'\n')
                    v.speak('The answer is: '+str(sca))

                except UnicodeEncodeError:

                    v.speak('The answer is: '+str(sca))

                except:

                    print('Google Results for: '+str(message))
                    url='http://google.com/search?q='+str(message)
                    webbrowser.open(url)
                    v.speak('Google Results for: '+str(message))

            elif how in message:                                                          #what happens when 'how' keyword is recognized

                try:

                    scq = cl.query(message)
                    sca = next(scq.results).text
                    print('\nThe answer is: '+str(sca)+'\n')
                    v.speak('The answer is: '+str(sca))

                except UnicodeEncodeError:

                    v.speak('The answer is: '+str(sca))

                except:

                    print('Google Results for: '+str(message))
                    url='http://google.com/search?q='+str(message)
                    webbrowser.open(url)
                    v.speak('Google Results for: '+str(message))

            elif stoplst in message:                                                        #what happens when stoplst keyword is recognized
                v.speak("I am shutting down")
                print("Shutting down...")
                break

            elif lsp in message:

                v.speak('Listening is paused')
                print('Listening is paused')
                r2 = sr.Recognizer()
                r2.pause_threshold = 0.7
                r2.energy_threshold = 400

                while True:

                    with sr.Microphone() as source2:

                        try:

                            audio2 = r2.listen(source2, timeout = None)
                            message2 = str(r.recognize_google(audio2))

                            if lsc in message2:
                                v.speak('I am listening')
                                break

                            else:
                                continue

                        except sr.UnknownValueError:
                            print("Listening is paused. Say resume listening when you're ready...")

                        except sr.RequestError:
                            v.speak("I'm sorry, I couldn't reach google")
                            print("I'm sorry, I couldn't reach google")


            else:
                pass

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("For a list of commands, say: 'keyword list'...")

        except sr.RequestError:
            v.speak("I'm sorry, I couldn't reach google")
            print("I'm sorry, I couldn't reach google")

    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: If i want to make it , record then anaylse, how?

Comment: It looks like robust code on a scan through, but there's far too much of it to be reviewed here. Please reduce this question down to what you think is the offending code.

Comment: maybe try to debug it step-by-step starting with the microphone , and since you said it works on your computer but not on the raspberry, maybe the raspberry `device_index` is a different index than that on your computer. So maybe start by inspecting `sr.Microphone(device_index = 7, ...` and the [documentation on Microphone()](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#microphonelist_microphone_names)